# transferring web page into web service

Tags: asp.net-web-api, html

Suppose we have a primary web page that most of our business logic in form of modules will appear inside this web page and it will trigger lots of other functionalities, something like **dotnet nuke default.aspx**. ***we are going to use this web form in a mobile application***, my question is, is it possible to transfer my primary web page via web Api or in other word adding a web service endpoint at top of Web Page(layer) to transmit both web page UI and its logic?
Thanks.